# ambiguous overloads in Scala

Tags: scala, slf4j

Trying to write a wrapper to slf4j.

wrote the methods. 2 of them are:

```
def logWarn(message: => String, arg1: => AnyRef) = { 

    if (logger.isWarnEnabled) {

        logger.warn(message, arg1)
    }
}

def logWarn(message: => String, args: => Array[AnyRef]) = {
    if (logger.isWarnEnabled) {
        logger.warn(message, args)
    }
}
```

This compiles nicely. Problem is trying to invoke:

```
logWarn("retried: {}. Error is: {}", Array[AnyRef](numOfRetries.toString(), e.toString()));
```

I would expect Scala to know I mean to call the second method above. for some reasons I get this error:

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method logWarn in trait Slf4jLogger of type
(message: => String, args: => Array[AnyRef])Unit
and  method logWarn in trait Slf4jLogger of type (message: => String, arg1: => AnyRef)Unit 
match argument types (java.lang.String,Array[AnyRef])
```

What's going on?

Comment: See explanation in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325086/why-is-scalas-behavior-in-case-of-overloading-with-by-name-parameters-different][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325086/why-is-scalas-behavior-in-case-of-overloading-with-by-name-parameters-different

Answer (score 1):

`Array[_]` is a subtype of `AnyRef`, hence any call with a 2nd argument of type `Array[AnyRef]` would be valid for both methods.

Without by-name parameters, you could easily work around this by using varargs:

```
def logWarn(message: => String, args: AnyRef*) {
  if (logger.isWarnEnabled) {
    logger.warn(message, args)
  }
}
```

However by-name params aren't compatible with varargs (in 2.9.1 at least). This means that `args: (=> AnyRef)*` is not valid.